# Combining the load and fadein function + a tiny bouns mission

Tags: jquery, ajax, dynamic, load, fadein

**Howdy folks!**

I know this has been solved a couple of times, but I can't seem to get it right in my case after looking through other questions. So here goes.

I've made this undotted list into a menu with 7 items.

```
    <ul id="om-ropox-menu">
        <li class="undotted"><a href="1">1</a></li>
        <li class="undotted"><a href="2">2</a></li>
        <li class="undotted"><a href="3">3</a></li>
        <li class="undotted"><a href="4">4</a></li>
        <li class="undotted"><a href="5">5</a></li>
        <li class="undotted"><a href="6">6</a></li>
        <li class="undotted"><a href="7">7</a></li>      
    </ul>
```

The href attr does not have extentions, because I need it this way, and I'll just let the javascript deal with that. So whenever the user clicks one of the links I'll have this javascript code

```
    //on page load, get this file
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#about_content').load('subpages/content_about/con_1.php');
    $('#about_content').fadeIn(1000);

    //handle menu clicks
    $('ul#om-ropox-menu li a').click(function(){
          var page = $(this).attr('href');
          $('#about_content').load('subpages/content_about/con_'+page+'.php', function(){
         });
     return false;
    });
});
```

This loads content from external php files, to be shown when the user clicks one of the 7 links. (con_1.php, con_2.php... con_7.php).

Notice that the div has a class which hides it (display:hidden; in CSS).

But rather than just loading the content I'd like the containing div to fadeIn and folddown by jQuery, so what am I missing here?

**Bonus mission (coudn't use question in title, lol)**
Can I modify the javascript to take, let's say get variable the first time the user arrives at the page. Let's say I'll give them to "jump right" into #4 via a href link from somewhere else?

Cheers!

**Edit**

i got it workign with the fadeIn function, so content fades nicely in on load now. This is what I have.

```
    //on page load, get this file
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#about_content').load('subpages/content_about/con_om.php', function(){
        $(this).fadeIn(1000)
        });

    //handle menu clicks
    $('ul#om-ropox-menu li a').click(function(){
        var page = $(this).attr('href');
        $('#about_content').fadeOut(1000, function() {
             $(this).load('subpages/content_about/con_'+page+'.php', function() {
             $(this).foldd(1000);
         });
         })
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Have you tried chaining the .fadeIn on the second .load?

Comment: the load method has a callback parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Try something more like :

```
<ul id="om-ropox-menu">
    <li class="undotted"><a href="#1">1</a></li>
    <li class="undotted"><a href="#2">2</a></li>
    <li class="undotted"><a href="#3">3</a></li>
    <li class="undotted"><a href="#4">4</a></li>
    <li class="undotted"><a href="#5">5</a></li>
    <li class="undotted"><a href="#6">6</a></li>
    <li class="undotted"><a href="#7">7</a></li>      
</ul>​
```

js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var page = document.location.hash.substring(1) || '1';
    $('#about_content').load('subpages/content_about/con_'+page+'.php', function() {
        $(this).fadeIn(1000);
    });

    $('#om-ropox-menu li a').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        page = $(this).attr('href').substring(1);
        $('#about_content').fadeOut(1000, function() {
            $(this).load('subpages/content_about/con_'+page+'.php', function() {
                $(this).fadeIn(1000);
            });
        })
    });
});​
```

Comment: For some reason that script does not work. I'm still kind of stuck. I'm looking into the callback function which @fliim mentioned...